# .htaccess RewriteRule with parameters doesn't seem to be working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I managed to get this Rewriterule to work :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]
```

that basically rewrites `my_project/admin.php -> my_project/admin & my_project/login-admin.php -> my_project/login-admin`

The problem is that my second rule is for my page that adds users into my database using a table parameter isn't working, what i need to show on the URL is my file name "add-client" and the table parameter "tb1", it should look like this

```
my_project/add-client.php?tb=tb1 -> my_project/add-client/tb1
```

i tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)\/?$ $1.php?tb=$2 [NC]
```

Does the fact that those two rules are in the same htaccess file makes any problem? please help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can set htacces.

> my_project/admin.php -> my_project/admin AND my_project/login-admin.php -> my_project/login-admin

```
RewriteRule ^my_project/admin$ my_project/admin.php [L,NC]
```

> my_project/add-client.php?table=table1 -> my_project/add-client/table1

```
RewriteRule ^my_project/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ yourfile.php?tb=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @Dilek, but i think i didnt specify my problem enough, my bad. So, i figured your first rule would do well with admin and login-admin pages, but i've got more files with similar name, all of them has two words divided by one dash, that's why my first rule was just fine.

Comment: The problem is that my second rule is for my page that adds users into my database using a table parameter isn't working, what i need to show on the URL is my file name "add-client" and the table parameter "tb1". I'll edit my question, sorry for the lacking details and inconsistencies here and there.

Comment: Try this : `RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/?$ $1.php?tb=$1 [NC]`. it will work if you are not linking table with id instead tableName in php and if you dont call to multiple table with same parameters, if you are calling multiple tables! then you need to give a name to each one like this : `RewriteRule ^mytable2/([a-z-]+)/?$ $1.php?tb=$1 [NC]` calling just id or just name is always `tb=$1` but if you are calling name and id then its `tbID=$1&tbname=$2`